# How to turn text into emoticons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway that i can turn text into emoticons. For example if text is `:)` i want to replace it with the smiley face emoticon like this one --> [image]

As it happens in kik , facebook etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Jquery CSS Emoticons](http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/) plugin.

Import:

```
<link href="stylesheets/jquery.cssemoticons.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.cssemoticons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">
  Hi, this is a great plugin! :-)
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.comment').emoticonize();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uheqgkf0/)

Answer (score 1):

We can use content editable for this, here is the principle *minus some other quirks you will run into ( like cursor placement )*

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"> </div>
```

Using some jquery

```
$("#editor").on("blur keyup paste input", function() {

  var content = $(this).html(),
  smiley =  "<img src='smiley.png' alt='smiley'/>";
  content = content.replace(/:)/g, smiley);
  $(this).html(content);

});
```

To get the value from the contenteditable is close to the same of how you get the value for the input - use `.html()` instead of `.val()`

```
var valuetosend = $("#editor").html();
```